# How can I display a confirmation message in a SettingsFragment before a user changes a ListPreference value?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, listpreference

I have a ListPreference in my SettingsFragment and I'd like to display a warning message when the user changes the value with a confirmation button. Only if the user confirms will the ListPreference value actually be changed to the selection. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

This is an older question, but here's an answer in case anyone else needs it. First there's an explanation, and at the end there's working code.

If I understand you correctly, you need to add a positive button (e.g. "Ok" or "Yes"), which actually makes the change, instead of making the change immediately when a list item is clicked. Something like this:

[image: Example using the code below]

---

### Explanation

`ListPreference` overrides the `onClick` method of the list items in `onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder)`, so that:

> Clicking on an item simulates the positive button click, and dismisses the dialog.

It also overrides the listener of the positive button (i.e. removes it) in the same method, with this explanation:

> The typical interaction for list-based dialogs is to have click-on-an-item dismiss the dialog instead of the user having to press 'Ok'.

You need to override it again, but without that functionality. This is the piece of code (inside `onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder)`) that does that and you want to get rid of:

```
builder.setSingleChoiceItems(mEntries, mClickedDialogEntryIndex, 
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                mClickedDialogEntryIndex = which;

                /* Clicking on an item simulates the positive button
                 * click, and dismisses the dialog. */
                ListPreference.this.onClick(dialog, DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE); // <--- don't want this
                dialog.dismiss(); // <--- don't want this
            }
        }
);

builder.setPositiveButton(null, null); // <--- don't want this
```

You also need to apply the change after clicking the positive button, which is done in `onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult)`.

So you need to create a custom class that extends `ListPreference` and override `onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder)` and `onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult)`.

---

### Code

Here's an example of a `ConfirmationListPreference` that I use:

```
package com.your.pckg;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Build;
import android.preference.ListPreference;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

public class ConfirmationListPreference extends ListPreference
{
    /** Holds the index of the selected item. */
    private int mClickedDialogEntryIndex;

    // Constructors; these are standard and required for the subclass
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ConfirmationListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public ConfirmationListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
    public ConfirmationListPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }
    public ConfirmationListPreference(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(AlertDialog.Builder builder)
    {
        // not calling the super method (the one from ListPreference), since
        // that's the one that disables the positive button functionality,
        // but we'll use most of its code, all except the parts we don't want

        if (getEntries() == null || getEntryValues() == null)
        {
            throw new IllegalStateException("ConfirmationListPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array.");
        }

        // get the index of the selected item
        mClickedDialogEntryIndex = findIndexOfValue(this.getValue());

        builder.setSingleChoiceItems(getEntries(), mClickedDialogEntryIndex,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        // update the index of the selected (clicked) item
                        mClickedDialogEntryIndex = which;

                        // the stuff we don't want is removed
                        // ...
                    }
                }
        );

        // and don't set the positive button listener to null
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDialogClosed(boolean positiveResult)
    {
        // we can't use the super method because mClickedDialogEntryIndex
        // is private and there's no setter, so we'll just copy its code

        if (positiveResult && mClickedDialogEntryIndex >= 0 && getEntryValues() != null)
        {
            String value = getEntryValues()[mClickedDialogEntryIndex].toString();

            if (callChangeListener(value))
            {
                setValue(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you use it in your preference xml (e.g. `pref_general.xml`) like this:

```
<com.your.pckg.ConfirmationListPreference
    android:key="@string/key_pref_app_language"
    android:title="@string/pref_app_language_title"
    android:entries="@array/pref_app_language_list_titles"
    android:entryValues="@array/pref_app_language_list_values"
    android:defaultValue="0"
    android:negativeButtonText="@string/button_title_cancel"
    android:positiveButtonText="@string/button_title_ok"
    />
```